# Factory with generic method parameter, return type and interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, factory

I have a factory for creating model instances. The factory provides this method:

```
public <Model> Model createFromJson(String json, final Class<Model> model) { 
    Model modelInstance = gson.fromJson(json, model);
    ((IModel)modelInstance).onCreateFromJson();
    return modelInstance;
}
```

As you can see I cast the instance of the model (previously given as class method parameter) to an interface, so I can call specific methods.
Further the generic return type works nice as well, since the caller must not cast any object. It's simply enough to call:

```
MyModel myModel = ModelFactory.getInstance().createFromJson(json, MyModel.class);
```

But, unfortunately, I can call the factory method with ANY kind of object, like:

```
Integer myTest = ModelFactory.getInstance().createFromJson(json, Integer.class);
```

So I would like to define the factory method parameter to be of type IModel. But I can't figure out how, since I'm passing a class, and not an instance of a Model (IModel).

So, actually I am searching for something like this:

```
public <Model<? extends IModel>> Model 
    createFromJson(String json, final Class<Model<? extends IModel>> model)
```

Can anyone give me advice?

Comment: Is the `Integer` in the second call, the java.lang.Integer? If that's the case, then you can not implement this because the only common super class/interface between `Integer` and `Model` (which I assume you've implemented), can be `Object` and casting Object into `IModel` will be inevitable, which again will fail if an `Integer` value is passed..

Comment: Thanks guys. The solution was more simple than expected. I would accept all of your answers, but since I can only accept one I chose Veger's answer, because of the hint for using only one letter for the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Model` as name for your type parameter is confusing since you also seem to have a class named `Model`. Instead use `M` or some other letter.

To specify which class a type must extend you need to use this:

```
M extends IModel
```

Or using it for your example code:

```
public <M extends IModel> M createFromJson(String json, final Class<M> model) {
  // Method code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want

```
public <T extends IModel> T createFromJson(String json, Class<T> model)
```

Answer (score 2):

The method should define the bounds of the template parameter as follows:

```
public <T extends Model> T createFromJson(String json, final Class<T> model)
{
    T modelInstance = gson.fromJson(json, model);
    ((IModel) modelInstance).onCreateFromJson();
    return modelInstance;
}
```

BTW, in your definition, all references to `Model` are actually referring to template parameter and not the Model class, I guess you get that point.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought this is what you want:

```
public <T extends IModel<T>> T createFromJson(String json, final Class<T> model)
{
    T modelInstance = gson.fromJson(json, model);
    ((IModel) modelInstance).onCreateFromJson();
    return modelInstance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If you correct the Model<T> to IModel i will upvote your answer.

Comment: @ChristopherWill Deal! I've edited it. Actually, I wasn't sure whether to code it as IModel from the start - I kinda skimmed the question cos I am a bit busy ATM :)